# Function that converts DataFrame to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a transformer call `Dictifier()` that encapsulates converting a DataFrame using `.to_dict("records")` as I want to use it in a `pipeline`.

I want to be able to incorporate the function inside pipeline like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
                     ("featureunion", numeric_categorical_union),
                     ("dictifier", Dictifier()),
                     ("vectorizer", DictVectorizer(sort=False)),
                     ("clf", xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth = 3))
                     ])
```

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) ... Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Is there a specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this leaning on a pipeline of sklearn (comment if you are using another kind of pipeline object). You should build a class with two methods: fit and transform for each specific step you want to create for your pipeline.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3],
                   'y': [4,5,6]})

class dataframe2dict(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self):
        """Mock method"""
        return self

    def transform(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        return df.to_dict()


pipeline = make_pipeline(dataframe2dict())

pipeline.transform(df)
```

Comment: Omg Thank you so much!